# How to set value on input field from other page using onclick through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass value from page1.html to page2.html. However, nothing happens as open the page2.html as fill out the input field.

How should I do to fix it?

**Page1.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="pname" data-id="barcode-number" onclick="goforward(this);">Prod</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function goforward(d) {
          var r = d.getAttribute("data-id");
          var detailsWindow = window.open('page2.html');
          detailsWindow.onload = function{
            document.getElementById('prod0').value = p1name;
            document.getElementById('prod1').value = p2name;
          }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**Page2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <div class="md_product">
        <input id="prod0" value="Product One">
        <input id="prod1" value="Product Two">
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You can use local storage for this

Comment: pass with in url query like `second.html?data=string`

Comment: Or in the hash part of the URL: `second.html#data=string`. This way the URL parameters are not sent to the server; they are seen by the Javascript in the second page.

Comment: Use detailsWindow.document

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS localstorage to achieve your requirements.
Here is one case that can solve your problem.

Page 1:

```
<body>
    <div class="pname" data-id="barcode-number" onclick="goforward(this);">Prod</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function goforward(d) {
          var r = d.getAttribute("data-id");
          var detailsWindow = window.open('page2.html');
          detailsWindow.onload = function{
            let val1 = document.getElementById('prod0').value = p1name;
            localStorage.setItem('prod0', 'val1');
            let val2 = document.getElementById('prod1').value = p2name;
            localStorage.setItem('prod1', 'val2');
          }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Page 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <div class="md_product">
        <input id="prod0" value="Product One">
        <input id="prod1" value="Product Two">
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var prod0 = localStorage.getItem("prod0");
        var prod1 = localStorage.getItem("prod1");
        document.getElementById('prod0').value=prod0;
        document.getElementById('prod1').value=prod1;
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass perameters in render url like /page2?param1=textbox1value,param2=textbox2value